# latched topic and rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, markerarray, latch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have some constant data published as MarkerArray topics so it can be seen in rviz.

Instead of streaming constant data, I thought it would be much more optimal to use latched topics to publish the data once and sending it when it is needed.

However, it does not work that well: in rviz, the first time the marker is rendered it is ok, but if the rendering stops for some reason (i.e. I restart the demo and some tf frames are temporarily not available for instance), it is not displayed anymore.

Is this a bug? What would be the best strategy in order to keep a consistent display?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27817/latched-topic-and-rviz/) by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4478 on 2012-02-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-16**:
I have the same problem. Sometimes everything displays fine, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, so I opened a ticket here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5374 Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0